# Javascript: onSubmit function submits form before function has finished?

Tags: javascript, forms, onsubmit

I'm asking this because I am at a complete loss myself and need a fresh pair of eyes.

The following JavaScript function is successfully called on submission of the connected HTML form. The function starts and the first two `if` statements run (and halt the submission if they return `false`).

Then, the first test `alert` "before" appears and then the form submits, completely missing out the rest of the function. While testing I changed the final line to return `false` so that whatever happen the function should return `false`, but the form still submitted.

```
function validateForm(form)
{
    // declare variables linked to the form
    var _isbn = auto.isbn.value;
    var _idisplay = auto.isbn.title;
    var _iref = "1234567890X";
    // call empty string function
    if (EmptyString(_isbn,_idisplay)==false) return false;
    // call check against reference function
    if (AgainstRef(_isbn,_iref,_idisplay)==false) return false;
    // call check length function
    alert("before");///test alert

    ////// FORM SUBMITS HERE?!? /////////////

    if (AutoLength(_isbn)==false) return false;
    alert("after");///test alert
    // if all conditions have been met allow the form to be submitted
    return true;
}
```

---

Edit: this is what `AutoLength` looks like:

```
function AutoLength(_isbn) {
    if (_isbn.length == 13) {
        return true; {
    else {
        if (_isbn.length == 10) {
            return true; {
        else {
            alert("You have not entered a valid ISBN10 or ISBN13. Please correct and try again.");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you call that function from?

Comment: @greut It is called from the opening tag (<form...>) of the HTML form using - onSubmit="return validateAuthor(this)

Comment: What does the `AutoLength` function do? Does it throw an `Error`? (Check you JavaScript console.)

Comment: don't you have any javascript error happening which would make that function to be exited sooner, like `AutoLength` check the error console.

Comment: @PPvG AutoLength checks to see if the isbn entered in the form is either 10 or 13 characters long.

Comment: @user1149225: I'm sorry, I meant *can you show us* what `AutoLength` does? Because if it throws an `Error`, your function will not return `false` and the `<form>` will be submitted.

Comment: @greut Now I'm am showing my lack of true javascript knowledge/experience (and I was doing so well), how would I check the error console in Chrome

Comment: @PPvG  An error is being thrown but it flash up and diappears so fast in the error console I can't read it. The AutoLength function is as follows `function AutoLength(_isbn){
  if (_isbn.length==13)
  {
    return true;
  {
  else
  {
    if (_isbn.length==10)
    {
      return true;
    {
    else
    {
      alert ("You have not entered a valid ISBN10 or ISBN13. Please correct and try again.");
      return false;
    }
  }`

Comment: Ok I've figured ho to read the error, it's saying: Uncaught ReferenceError: AutoLength is not defined. I assume that means it can't find the function to call?

Comment: @user1149225: yes, it does. It says that because AutoLength is missing some closing braces. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are errors in your implementation of `AutoLength`. Currently, it looks like this:

```
function AutoLength(_isbn) {
    if (_isbn.length == 13) {
        return true; { // <------ incorrect brace
    else {
        if (_isbn.length == 10) {
            return true; { // <------ incorrect brace
        else {
            alert("You have not entered a valid ISBN10 or ISBN13. Please correct and try again.");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

See how it doesn't close all of its blocks? That's because you've used the wrong brace in two places, and you've forgotten to close the function.

You could rewrite the function like this:

```
function AutoLength(_isbn) {
    return _isbn.length === 13  || _isbn.length === 10;
}
```

If you're hell-bent on using `alert`, you can do that inside `validateForm` (although I would try to find a more user-friendly way to show the error message).

In the future, when you're trying to debug code, you can use `try` and `catch` to "catch" `Errors` as they happen, like this:

```
try {
    if (false === AutoLength(_isbn)) {
        return false;
    }
} catch (e) {
    alert('AutoLength threw an error: '+e.message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what a stupid mistake. As I said I needed a fresh pair of eyes, had been staring at these bits of code for ages.

Comment: This is why you should strive to keep functions as small and elegant as possible. Notice how succinct his implementation is? A one-liner that can be easily understood.

Answer (score 0):

If the execution of the function is terminated by a runtime error, the form submits. So check out the script console log for error messages.

Comment: Indeed, probably the auto or auto.isbn are undefined at the moment or one of the validation functions is not